# Get @RequestMapping value of different method in same controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

Using Spring Boot, I have a couple methods in my `RegisterController` which handles new user registration.

The `createNewUser` method is responsible for saving the new user to the database and sending a confirmation e-mail containing a link that has a unique token.

The `confirmUser` method handles processing the GET request for the confirmation link.

Is there a way for the `createNewUser` method to get the `@RequestMapping` value assigned to `confirmUser`?   I'd like to use this value to generate the confirmation link instead of hard coding it.

```
// Process form input data
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

}

// Process confirmation link
// Link in confirmation e-mail will be /registerConfirmation?token=UUID
@RequestMapping(value="/registerConfirmation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmUser( @RequestParam("token") String token) {

}
```

Comment: Why dont you merge confirmUser service with createNewUser, which would apparently return confirmation response.

Comment: @PratikAmbani Because confirmUser() should only get invoked when the user clicks on the confirmation link in the e-mail.   The createNewUser() method is when they have successfully filled out the register form.

Comment: BTW it's not a good practice to change state on HTTP GET requests (I guess you update the user info in the DB to note that he's confirmed), so it would be a better practice to change your 'confirmUser' method to be HTTP POST.

Comment: @AlonSegal good point...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get it from the `@RequestMapping` value but you have a couple of different options.

Option 1: Create a constant for the mapping and use that which allows you to reference it in both methods.

```
private final static String REGISTER_CONF_VAL = "/registerConfirmation";

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

}

// Process confirmation link
// Link in confirmation e-mail will be /registerConfirmation?token=UUID
@RequestMapping(value=REGISTER_CONF_VAL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmUser( @RequestParam("token") String token) {

}
```

Option 2: Less ideal, but if you add `registerConfirmation` to your config file, you can access it like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="${register.conf.val}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView confirmUser( @RequestParam("token") String token) {

}
```

The reason this isn't ideal is because you probably don't want it to be different from environment to environment. That said, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate the link based on user request, you can use the Path Variable in the controller. U can get the path variable and use some mechanism to validate the path as well.

Replace registerConfirmation with {registerConfirmation}  and in the method, use @PathVariable annotation to get the path. Use the variable to check if the path is valid.